# Setting session in JSP and getting session in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am setting a session attribute in JSP code as below and submitting the HTTP form to servlet:

```
session.setAttribute("qnaInfo", qnaInfo);
System.out.println("session.getAttribute" + session.getAttribute("qnaInfo"));
```

I am trying to get session attribute in a servlet code as below:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
AuthQnAInfo storedQnaInfo = (AuthQnAInfo) session.getAttribute("qnaInfo");
```

In servlet it is null only on IE. But in Chrome I get the value.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: IE is probably configured to reject cookies.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I Enabled cookies in Internet Explorer. Before the level of blocking cookies was Medium, i made it Low and i could get the session data in my servlet even in IE. But, what is the solution for this? I cannot do the same on all the machines, where ever i host my application. So please suggest something.

Comment: Maybe the problem only occurs when the server is localhost, and won't happen in production?

Comment: I have not deployed my app yet on production. I am not sure about it. But does it really matters, if the server is on localhost or production?

Comment: No idea. It depends on what those "medium" and "low" level do. I don't use IE myself.

Answer (score 1):

in all browsers ,the session.getAttribute("aaaa") is working , try ones

Answer (score 0):

From [How can I enable session tracking for JSP pages if the browser has disabled cookies?](http://interview.fyicenter.com/196_JSP_General_Session_Tracking_without_Cookies.html):

> If the browser does not support cookies, or if cookies are disabled, you can still enable session tracking using URL rewriting. URL rewriting essentially includes the session ID within the link itself as a name/value pair.
> However, for this to be effective, you need to append the session ID for each and every link that is part of your servlet response. Adding the session ID to a link is greatly simplified by means of of a couple of methods: response.encodeURL() associates a session ID with a given URL, and if you are using redirection, response.encodeRedirectURL() can be used by giving the redirected URL as input.
>
> Both encodeURL() and encodeRedirectedURL() first determine whether cookies are supported by the browser; if so, the input URL is returned unchanged since the session ID will be persisted as a cookie.